# Function does not exist then dumping mariadb database to remote host

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, restore, mysqldump

Im trying to do an initial transfer of my data to a replica server by running this command:

`sudo mysqldump -f -u root -pPassword --opt mydb | mysql --host=replica01 -C mydb -u restore -pPassword`

It copies most of the data, but stops on one of the functions i've created with this error:

> ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 3750: FUNCTION mydb.myFunction does not exist
> mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write

I have both procedures and functions in my database. Some procedures use functions in them. Is that what is causing this? In that case, what can i do to ignore these errors?

Comment: Any functions that are used need to be defined before they are used.  Try editing the dump and shift them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try doing mysqldump without the stored procedures

In your case, it would be

```
sudo mysqldump -f -u root -pPassword --skip-routines -opt mydb | mysql --host=replica01 -C mydb -u restore -pPassword
```

You should also dump the stored procedures into a text file

See my old post [Dump only the Stored Procedures in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/dump-only-the-stored-procedures-in-mysql/4089#4089)

In your case it would be

```
mysqldump -f -u root -pPassword --routines --skip-triggers --no-data --no-create-info -opt mydb > mydb_sp.sql
```

Have a look at the file

```
less mydb_sp.sql
```

then import the stored procedures like this

```
mysql --host=replica01 -C mydb -u restore -pPassword < mydb_sp.sql
```

Comment: Turned out procedures were skipped, but there was a view that utilized one of them. Marked as answer as it put me in the right track. Thank you!